# What REST urls should be used for accessing data from a many-2-many table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, many-to-many

What should be the syntax of the REST calls for manipulating (e.g. insert/update/delete) a many-2-many table as mentioned below for my Rails app.

```
create table foos (id integer(11), name varchar(255))
create table bars (id integer(11), name varchar(255))
create table foo_bars (foo_id integer(11), bar_id integer(11)
foo_id FK foos(id)
bar_id FK bars(id)
```

Should I use something like?

```
POST /foo/:fooid/bar (to create fooid, barid)
PUT /foo/:fooid/bar/:barid (to update fooid, barid)
DELETE /foo/:fooid/bar/:barid (to delete a foo_id, bar_id combination)
```

Comment: This question is being marked down probably because it is too vague.  Try adding some more information about your schema and what you want to do.

Comment: It depends on what Foo and Bar is in your application and leave it 5 different rails developers and you will have at least 4 different solutions. REST is a pattern or design philosophy - not a golden rule that gives some kind of universal mapping from database to URLs. Voting to close.

Comment: I just added more information about the schema. I do understand that it could have 4 different solutions and I just want to make sure if I am modelig this correct. REST usually acts on a single resource, but in the above case Foo, Bar are those resources. But for the many-to-many representation I need to know if I should build a separate resource or piggyback on the Foo or Bar interface?

Comment: Can you describe a  bit more what kind of entity you are interacting with and how do you interact with them ?

Comment: @KevDev Foo is a User and Bar is a Book, we are trying to model a lending management system. Let me know if you need further information. User could borrow many books and at the same time a Book could be borrowed by multiple users over a period of time.

Comment: @Rpj Make it a bit more clear. How do you manages the books id. Does each book have a single id even if they are the same edition ? I guess I would create an enpoint  /books/rental or book/borrow to manage it then it will make sense to send POST PUT and DELETE request to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider using a third endpoint, maybe named `checkouts`, to represent a book checked out by a user, just like your foo-bars table. I think it's advisable because the relationship has other information associated with it besides just the user and book ids. For instance, when is the book due back? You can also use this endpoint to track historical information about the historical activity of a book or user. I'm using a boolean for example purposes, but a date would be more appropriate.

```
// check out some books from the library
POST /checkouts
{ "userId":25, "bookIds": [ 12, 45, 341 ] }

// renew the checkout for another month
PUT /checkouts 
{
    "user": "/users/25",
    "book": "/books/12",
    "dueBack": 1438612187,
    "returned": false,
    ...
}

// get all books currently checked out by Bob
GET /checkouts?userId=25&returned=false
{
    "checkouts" : [ {
        "user": "/users/25",
        "book": "/books/12",
        "dueBack": 1438612187,
        "returned": false,
        ...
    },
    ...
    ]
}

// find the checkout history of War and Peace
GET /checkouts?bookId=12
```